# PHP Sendmail sender name is always Apache when header have attachment

Tags: php, apache, sendmail

We are trying to send an email using sendmail. Everything works fine with normall headers but the moment we add attachment in the header, the sender name comes as Apache. Here is our code snippet

```
$from_email = "noreply@domain.com";
$separator = md5(time());
$eol = PHP_EOL;
$filename = "attachment.pdf";
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($filename)));
$text = "Hi!";

// main header (multipart mandatory)
$headers  = "From:".$from_email.$eol;
$headers  = "Bcc:user@domain.com".$eol;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"".$eol.$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol;
$headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message.".$eol.$eol;
// message
$message .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
$message .= $text.$eol.$eol;

// attachment
$message .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$message .= "Content-Type: application/pdf".$eol;
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
$message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"".$eol;
$message .= $attachment.$eol;
$message .= "--".$separator."--".$eol;

$b = mail($email, "Your Issue of the STQ",$message, $headers, "-fnoreply@domain.com");
```

By Adding -fnoreply@domain.com, we are getting like this in email header From: noreply@domain.com (Apache). Not sure where this Apache is coming from?

What could be the problem here.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a dot on the second line.

```
$headers  = "From:".$from_email.$eol;
$headers  .= "Bcc:user@domain.com".$eol;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the header like this :

```
$headers .= 'From: <webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n";
```

Also missing the dot on the second line as xyzz pointed